# How to print the description of file in colored font in apache2?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2-module

In Apache, we can add the description of file by adding the following(similar) in file `/etc/apache2/mods-available`:

```
AddDescription "your message" filepath with respect to your shared directory
```

But how can we set the `font color` of the `"your message"` in description. For example take a look of following image:
[image]

I want the text under rectangular region with font color red. How can we do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding HTML message with the apache AddDescription directive. Quote from the apache documentation:

> Descriptive text defined with AddDescription may contain HTML markup,
>   such as tags and character entities. If the width of the description
>   column should happen to truncate a tagged element (such as cutting off
>   the end of a bolded phrase), the results may affect the rest of the
>   directory listing.

Example:

```
AddDescription "<p style='color: red;'>My Message</p>" /path/to/file/or/directory
```

This should work in apache 2.2 and 2.4. To read more about the mod_autoindex visit the apache docs:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription